# How to make automatic SIM card selection for specific contacts?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sim-card, automation, dual-sim

Everytime I call someone I change SIM card to one of them and call from that SIM card. Is it possible to assign a SIM card for each contact, so that when calling a contact the phone select the SIM card automatically based on the settings?

Even if a contact is saved in first SIM card but currently second is active, phone uses second to call.

Comment: I don't have a Samsung device but in my devices (with 4.2.1 and 4.4.2) the default contacts app has an option to associate SIM card with an individual contact. Open Contacts -> tap contact name -> press menu key and select Associate. See if you also have this option in your default said app

Comment: The menu contains only these: "Edit", "Delete", "Share namecard via", "Add to reject list", "Add shortcut to home". I can't find "Associate".

Comment: There are some specific [DualSIM apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=dualsim) helping you out here (I have no DualSIM device, so I cannot tell how well they work). Some dialer apps have specific support for this. The linked list is pretty short, so you might wish to check it. Also take a look at [this list](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=dual-sim): a bit longer, but might have better hits ;)

Comment: Related [playstore app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pixelrush.dualsimselector&hl=en)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lollipop versions, Goto

Settings -> Sim Cards -> Call settings -> Phone account settings -> Make calls with ->

Under this you will have three options

- Sim 1
- Sim 2
- Ask First

Select `Ask First` option from that menu and when you call someone from the contacts, you will be shown the Sim 1 and Sim 2 option. Select the `Remember SIM for number` checkbox and select the sim card you want to associate the contact to. The next time you call that contact it will automatically call using the sim you configured as default(It wont show you the sim selection iption). Do remember that you can always switch the sim cards while connecting to call by clicking `Change sim` option.

**Update:**

For Kitkat,

First you need to enable this feature in

```
Dual SIM settings -> Call settings -> Automatic SIM selection.
```

The  setting for Dual SIM settings->Call settings->Making calls should be set as “Ask every time I make a call”.

```
Dual SIM settings -> Call settings -> Making calls.
```

[image: Screenshot1]

Select `Remember SIM for number` and then select either SIM 1 or SIM 2 to make the call. The next time you  make a call to that contact it will automatically call using the sim you configured as default based on the call history.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Your answer is promising but in Galaxy S4 Mini, I can't find "Phone account settings" in "Call Settings" menu

Comment: @Ashot What is the os version of your phone?

Comment: Android version is 4.4.2

Comment: @Ashot updated the answer check the kitkat solution..see if you can find the settings in your Samsung mobile..i have motorola so it might be different..

Comment: Is the selection really based on the phone number? How can you use each sim to call your voice-mail number, which is identical for each SIM/provider? I'm using Android 5.0.2.

Comment: @Bas I don't think it's based on phone number. It's based on the SIM selection(SIM1 or SIM2). I cannot understand your second question.

Comment: @Lucky: Sorry I was not very clear. The screenshot has a check-box 'Remember SIM for number'. I was asking how that feature works, I live in the Netherlands where most telecom providers use the number 1233 to call your voice-mail box, if the remember SIM feature remembers your decision based on the number you are calling, I can't have 2 contacts (one for each provider) that uses the correct SIM to call to the respective voicemail-boxes.

Comment: i cant find this option in galaxy S5 with android 5.0
mainly i cant find "Dual SIM settings"

Comment: I can't find these settings in samsung core. Need help.

Comment: Is it possible to have an auto-selection of the used SIM based on the called number? Like for example if I call a number starting with +7, use SIM1, if +49, then SIM2, otherwise ask.

Comment: @DannyLo You should ask that as a [new question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).